# MS SQL xml query to file

Tags: sql-server, file, select, export

I need to save my query result in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio to specific path in the server.

I know that I can do it via bcp utility, but I have to use something else (because of the performance). Is it possible to do something like in MySQL?

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '[path]'
```

In my case I already converted my Select to XML structure (non-auto) so the only thing left is that I need to write it to file.

Comment: What's wrong with `BCP` I don't think it will be slow. In which format you are storing the result

Comment: But it looks terrible, and script has to be clearly and easy to change for later use. As I noticed I cannot move bcp select part to another line, because it destroy the syntax and create error in execute.ONE HUGE line of select is pretty illegible, thats why I need to use another way to save my query.

Comment: So, I assume, you have xml variable with all data which you need to write into a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries I realized that i can put my Select into Temporary Table what lets me easly manipulate selected data just before, parse it to XML and then put out from that TempTable into separated saved file. In the end when you have to save some query to files by bcp, and the select is large I recommend using TempTables.

Many thanks.